# Regular expression for phone number with special characters

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

I  need a regular expression for phone numbers. The phone numbers may contain special characters like `+, ., /, -, space, (, ), [, ]`.

**Some Examples:**

```
(+91) 9864081806
(+91)9864081806
(+91)(98640)81806
+91.98640.81806
[+91]09864081806
+91.986.408.1806
+91-986-408-1806
Maximum numbers = 15
```

The special characters can exists anywhere in the code. An opening bracket should have a closing one.

I have created this pattern but it does not work:

```
preg_match('/^[\[\(\0-9\s.\_\-\+\/\)\]]{3,15}$/', $phone_no)
```

Comment: You need to define your general rules for the matching as right now are too vague. For example: is this phone number valid `+91 12344 123 [[123]]`? As for your current rules It may be valid, however you probably don't want to allow such a thing... Please define all valid rules. Add extra examples for every rule.

Comment: (+91) 9864081806
(+91)9864081806
(+91)(98640)81806
+91.98640.81806
[+91]09864081806
+91.986.408.1806
+91-986-408-1806
Maximum numbers = 15

Comment: hi  i add some example of rules i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

`^(?=(?:[^\d\n]*\d){1,15}[])]?$)(?:[+]?\d++|[(][+]?\d++[)]|[[][+]?\d++[]])(?:[ .-]?+(?:\d\d++|[(]\d\d++[)]|[[]\d\d++[]]))*+$`

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/51FZ68/3/).